# Github API - Get contents of tag instead of master

Tags: git, github, github-api

As per the documentation of the github API - https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/ to get the contents of a repo or a file, I should be using `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path`

Based on that, if I want to get the contents of package.json file in this repo - https://github.com/fastly/epoch/tree/master (this repo is just used for example), I should do `"/repos/fastly/epoch/contents/package.json"`. This directly get the contents of the package.json file on master.

However in my case I want to get the contents of package.json file from one of the tags i.e. - `https://github.com/fastly/epoch/tree/0.6.0`

I tried whatever is available in github API for tags and trees, but nothing was helpful here - https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/ and https://developer.github.com/v3/git/tags/

How can I get the contents of the file under a tagged branch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the [Contents API documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents) it looks like you would simply use a query parameter to do this. Using your example, you would issue a `GET` to

```
/repos/fastly/epoch/contents/package.json?ref=0.6.0
```

A cURL request would look more like

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/fastly/epoch/contents/package.json?ref=0.6.0
```

Comment: Thanks @sigmavirus24! Adding '?ref=0.6.0' to the url didn't help. Will keep looking on around for the way to use ref in the url.

Comment: Hmmm I tried different ways and got it. It's - /repos/fastly/epoch/contents?ref=0.6.0 which gives list of files under this tag and looks like then I will have to find the file in the list and use it.

Comment: Are you using the correct [media type](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#custom-media-types)?

Comment: Actually just noticed, even the URL you posted works. Was my bad, the file name in there is case sensitive. I tried with 'P' instead of 'p' for package.json, hence it was not returning anything. My bad. Thanks @sigmavirus24!